# Synchronizing missing data on publisher and subscriber database tables (insert and update only missing data on destination) in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, transactional-replication

In my case, we have some extra data rows in few tables on subscriber database, which I need to retain.

I tried `tablediff.exe` utility which is traversing all the tables and creating Insert, update and delete queries in single SQL script, but I just need to insert/update and not delete.

I don't want to manually delete 'delete' statements from `tablediff.exe` generated scripts. I am looking for an option which does not look for data rows to be deleted and concentrate on insert and update rows.

If it is not going to work I have to look for the dynamic query using 'except'.

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you are asking, but you could try as a workaround to comment out DELETEs with Find and Replace.
Find what: DELETE FROM [
Replace with: --DELETE FROM [

But if it feels dangerous - you could just create a linked server and write a cross-server query which INSERTs/UPDATEs the difference.

Comment: Delete statements ar very high in the scripts and i don't want to go with this approach.